# How to identify the eclipse view get closed or not?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

When I close any view in eclipse, there must be some listener which detects the action.
Please provide me the way to identify the closing of a view in eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement o.e.ui.IPartListener and watch for partClosed

Comment: I am implementing the IPartListener in the myView class which is extending ViewPart but none of the overriden method are responding.

Comment: That is not correct. You need to create a separate class implementing IPartListener and then attach with IPartService.addPartListener()